# How to observe Text in the SwiftUI or pass String to the ViewModel in other way?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a problem. I am passing a string between views and use it, to the download data from the database. Then the string goes to the Text. I want to observe Text (not TextField) or pass String to the ViewModel in SwiftUI. I know how to do it in Textfield case, but there is possible in the Text?

View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RefuelingListView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel: RefuelingListViewModel
var vehicle: Vehicle

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        
        Text(vehicle.name)
        .font(.system(size: 24))
        .bold()
        .frame(width: 380, height: 60, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding(.top, -20)
        .padding(.leading, 10)
    
    List(viewModel.refuelings) { refueling in
        RefuelingListRow(refueling: refueling)
    }
    }
}
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 import Foundation

class RefuelingListViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var refuelings = [Refueling]()

private let persistenceService: PersistenceServiceProtocol

init(persistenceService: PersistenceServiceProtocol) {
    self.persistenceService = persistenceService
}
```

Comment: "Observing" `Text` doesn't really make sense because it doesn't have a changing value. You already have access to what's in the `Text` via `vehicle.name`. Are you just asking how to call a function on the view model?

Comment: Yep, but I want it in the View Model. Data for the vehicle.name comes from another view.

Comment: The two paths are generally: 1) Use `onAppear` in the view to send a value to the view model and load data 2) Use `init` on the view so that you can explicitly send an initial value to the view model (not really recommended, since `init` shouldn't do heavy work)

Comment: Can you show me any example? I mean onAppear.

Comment: I added an answer with a simple example. I couldn't use your types since they're not included here and it wasn't clear where the `vehicle.name` would be going, but it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here's an example of using `onAppear` to pass a value to an `ObservableObject`:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var myValue = ""
}

struct ContentView : View {
    private var myValue = "Updated value"
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.myValue)
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.myValue = myValue
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. You saved my time.